# Lecture Notes in Computer Science (LNCS): side by side figures

Tags: floats, lncs, sidebyside

I'm preparing a paper in overleaf that uses LNCS format to submit to a conference (Work-in-Progress (WiP)) and I'm trying to use side by side subfigures but I can't. I'm getting errors/I can't compile!

I'm using the following document class and the packages for the figures:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}


\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}





\begin{figure}[h]

      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{fig1.eps} 
      \caption{Caption1}
      \label{fig:subim1}
      \end{subfigure}

      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{fig2.eps}
      \caption{Caption 2}
      \label{fig:subim2}
      \end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}

\end{figure}

.
.
```

When I change the document class to "article", it works. But I want to use LNCS format.

P.S: The caption's format of the figure should be similar to the LNCS figure's caption's format.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you and regards,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get

```latex
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

)

! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption)                with the subfigure package.

See the subcaption package documentation for explanation.
```

The first message says that you should not use `caption` (loaded by `subcaption`) in the `llncs` class. The second says that `subfigure` and `subcaption` don't go along with each other.

By the way, `subfigure` has been replaced several years ago by `subfig`, which can be used with `llncs`. Also, `epsfig` should ***not*** be used in newer documents: use `graphicx` instead.

```latex
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[Caption1\label{fig:subim1}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Caption1\label{fig:subim2}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
}

\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :)